# else condition not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a button, and an h1 beneath it.
When the button is pressed, I want the body's background colour to change to the h1's colour.... and I want the h1's colour to change to the body's background colour.

I have the body's background colour and h1's colour as variables in RGB colour values.  Is there any way to achieve what I want to do within the on(click) event?

This is the code I have so far:

```
var bodyclr = $('body').css('background-color');
var textclr = $('h1').css('color');

// When user clicks on the .switch button
$('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log(bodyclr);
    console.log(textclr);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, should be easy, just store one of the colors, and swap ?

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var bg = $('body').css('background-color');

    $('body').css('background-color', $('h1').css('color'));

    $('h1').css('color', bg);

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/boy4a67d/)

Comment: Thanks! That works. 
I was thinking along the same line by calling the body background colour variable in the 4th line in your code.  But when I tried it, it didn't work.  I didn't think to use what you have in line 3:
  $('body').css('background-color', $('h1').css('color'));
What is achieved by that line?

Jquery noob here. 
Also, sorry for the mismatched question title... I was asking a different question before and didn't see the heading when I was asking this question.

Comment: @user3413191 `$('body').css('background-color', ...);` is used to set the background color of the `<body>` element. The `...` is the value to be used as the BG colour, and in this case it is simply the text color of `<h1>`, i.e. `$('h1').css('color')`

Comment: I see that I don't even need to store h1's colour as a variable. Just the body colour will do.